# Typescript AngularJS app with Salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com

I am new to Salesforce development and Apex. I would like to create a VisualForce page, but I prefer to work with my preferred IDE, tools, and workflow such as writing my AngularJS code with Typescript and compile and run my workflow using gulp. I have check the Canvas, but I don't really like the idea of iframe. Is there any way to do what I want within the force.com IDE or build it externally then deploy to force.com? Any guide will be helpful to get me started. Thanks.

Comment: I've made several visual force pages using [Jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/start/ ), with that library you can connect angularjs application with salesforce using pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to implement JavaScript-applications and you don't want care about back-end part as much as possible, I recommend you to look on [Visualforce Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects.htm), which provides ability to work with Salesforce objects right from JavaScript (CRUD operations).

Here is [a Simple Example of Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_example_simple.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your API client to have typings you could try [ts-force](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/ts-force).  I haven't used it with angular, but I have proven it's possible to develop react/typescript/visualforce applications locally using it.

I have an [example project](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/react-typescript-sfdx) that shows how you deal with connecting to the API (CORS proxy), packaging the app and deploying to salesforce.

*Disclaimer, I'm also the author of ts-force*